# Insane Burst of Copy Speed?

Tags: hard-drive, file-transfer, data-transfer

Check out the graph of this drive (SSD) to drive (7200 RPM) copy below.

When I first started the file copy it bursted up to past 700 MB/sec. Then, after bursting, it flatlines at ~100 MB/s for the duration of the file. How is it able to burst so high?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The transfer rate for Sata III is `600MBs` (considering `10b/8b` encoding). So the SSD is probably maxing that out (SSDs usually perform better with read speeds than write).

As for seeing these speeds in the hard drive: the reason is because part of the file you're transferring goes into the HDs [buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_buffer) (usually anywhere from `16MB` to `64MB`), which is solid-state memory. Once the buffer is filled, though, it must start writing to the physical disk (that's when you start seeing the slower speed).

You might also notice that this does not happen as often during read operations. The only occasion you can read a file from an HD at this speed is if it's already in the HD's buffer. During *write* operations, though, this is never a problem.

**Why are you getting transfer rates above `600MBs`?**

Well, it's most likely because there is part of the file already stored in RAM. This could be because you've recently read this file into ram (that image probably isn't the first go, right?).

Or, maybe the OS starts loading it into ram *before* you start the operation, like once you click the file. I've seen this, similarly, in Google Chrome - after you've typed a URL that you've already visited, it begins the HTTP request before you even press enter. A lot of applications may try to *guess* what you are going to do, in order to get a head start on intensive operations.

There is, otherwise, no way for the transfer rate to exceed the maximum bus speed.

**What's with the upwards slop in the graph?**

I can't say, with any sort of confidence, why you're seeing an upwards slop-like graph. This could be an effect of branch-prediction, but it's hard to say. It is, though, a good question to ask.

Comment: For another explanation for the `> 600 MB/s` speed, it is because it is storing the file in to ram using the systems own ram as another buffer. If the progress indicator included the write caching in it's speed calculations it is very understandable how you could reach those speeds.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I think I've added that in the **Edit:** section.

Answer (score 3):

This to my knowledge is the "burst" form burst rate - It occurs when the information is held in your Cache/Buffer rather then in your SSD memory

[Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burst_mode_(computing))

Comment: Your reference link is for the wrong topic. that is talking about internal CPU architectures.

Comment: And this is why I should have called in sick today - Updated the link to Burst mode (computing) - wiki. Closest I could find to what I was looking for